# Issues with SqlParameter constructor vs object initializer

Tags: c#, sqlparameter

Given the following line of code:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@displayId", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = customer.DisplayID);
```

I receive the following error:
The SqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null SqlParameter type objects, not String objects.

However, rewriting it to use object intialization:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@displayId", SqlDbType.NVarChar) { Value = customer.DisplayID });
```

works just fine.  Any pointer on why this is occuring?

Comment: May be because customer.DisplayId is null and SqlDbType.NVarChar doesn't accept null values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is a misplaced closing parenthesis:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@displayId", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = customer.DisplayId;
```

Note that there are 2 closing parentheses before `.Value`.  As you originally entered it, you are doing `cmd.Parameters.Add(...);` where the `...` is

`new SqlParameter("@displayId", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = customer.DisplayId`

and that evaluates to `customer.DisplayId`, hence the message about it not accepting `string` types.

Also, you can add the parameter more succinctly with

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@displayId", customer.DisplayId);
```

---

As to why `new SqlParameter("@displayId", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = customer.DisplayId` returns `customer.DisplayId`, consider that the [assignment operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbkb459w.aspx) returns the value being assigned as its result, and in this case that would be `customer.DisplayId`.  This is why you can assign a value to several variables at once:

```
int i, j, k;
i = j = k = 42;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@displayId", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = customer.DisplayID);
```

is the same as

```
var customerDisplayId = customer.DisplayID;
new SqlParameter("@displayId", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = customerDisplayId;
cmd.Parameters.Add(customerDisplayId);
```

now do you see why the compiler is complaining?